# table in the android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I have two table in a data base:
 1) student

```
   #_id## name ## 
    1     Bill
```

2) students_mark

```
  #_id# stud_id ## date ## marks
    1      1        12       50
    1      1        13       30
```

and I need to make this all came to the table with a title or not
marks should be changed and then overwritten in the database. 
table should look like this:

```
     name#       # marks# 
          # 1  # 2  #  3  #  4 # <<<date
     Bill # 60 # 43 # 30 # 23  # 
     tony # 34 # 34 # 33 # 32  #  
                         etc
```

**HOW DO THAT IN THE ANDROID?** explain, please.

Comment: Have you checked out [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)?

Answer (score 1):

First Look at this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

After that put id of column & row set dynamic data.

Comment: Thanks, i dont now how set dynamic data. Explain, please.